# Code coverage of inline functions using F# in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, code-coverage, inline

The code coverage tool in Visual studio 2012 marks all `inline` functions as uncovered even when they were covered.

Is there any way how to make code coverage work for `inline` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't inline functions directly integrated into the calling code? If so no actual method is called as the code is 'inlined' and for each place they are used a new copy of the inlined code exists.

Comment: This is probably correct. I was hoping to get answer like: there is an F# compiler switch which can globally deactivate all inline functions. But I guess that nothing like that exists...

Comment: The settings for f# are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) can't see anything appropriate. When you say not covered as actually showing as uncovered because the PDB will probably not have sequence points for those lines and so shouldn't mark them up - so it could be a rendering issue. Have you tried an alternative tool like [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) and see if it produces the same results.

Comment: So after a little bit of fighting, I got results out of OpenCover and the results are the same. Inline functions are not covered. EDIT: You can see results of the open cover here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4571/opencover/index.htm

Comment: Hmm interesting - do you have the project available for download?
It'll be interesting to se what is happening under the hood in the profiler.
Also can you break-point in the inlines?

Comment: Try this one: https://bitbucket.org/Oldrich/kit/src I have just realized that I cannot step into the inline functions. Strange...

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I don't have an answer just yet but it is is odd that you can't step into the inlines, of course it is no longer a "real" method but one would have though the debug points would have been mapped into the actual code during compilation.

Comment: It looks like when the IL is transferred from the source assembly to the methods in the target assembly (i.e. the test assembly because of inlining) by the compiler then the PDB information is also not copied across and is lost and so is not available for instrumentation. I'd probably raise this issue on the Microsoft Forums if you want to take it further.

Comment: You would raise this issue, or shall I? :) I do not know which forum to use to raise the issue. I was looking for a bug tracker of F# or similar but without any luck.

Comment: I think you should as it is more important to you than I - I think this would be the best forum - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fsharpgeneral/threads. 
PS. Does my answer still suffice even though it didn't fix your issue?

Answer (score 5):

When you write an `inline` function, the compiler inlines the body of the function into the calling code. As discussed in the comments, it also does not emit debug information for this inlined body (and so you cannot step into the function - I think this could be fixed - submit a request to `fsbugs` at `microsoft` dot `com`).

However, the compiler also generates a dynamic version of the code - if you write say:

```
let inline add a b = a + b
```

then there is actually an `add` method in the compiled code. The method will be generic (`'a -> 'b -> 'c`) and uses dynamic lookup to find an appropriate implementation of the `+` operator (because .NET generics cannot represent such constraints).

The dynamic implementation will be invoked when you use reflection or quotations:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
<@ add 1 2 @> |> LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation |> printfn "Got: %A"
```

If you put breakpoint inside `add` and run the above code than the breakpoint will be hit (and I assume the code coverage tool will report the function as covered).

But keep in mind that this is *not* the code that is actually executed when you write `add 1 2` in normal code - the code executing here is a different implementation (that uses slow dynamic lookup, rather than inlining).

Comment: I just tried this on a inline function with a well know code coverage tool and it did not work. The test with <@ @> ran correctly, but no highlighted code. Nice idea, will have to keep in mind.

Comment: Tomas's approach of adding a test for the inlined method via quotation can be done easily using Swensen.Unquote. The coverage shows up under OpenCover and NCrunch.